# Clickhouse is slow while "Merging aggregated data"

Tags: clickhouse

I'm watching Clickhouse performance. I noticed that queries are slow at "Merging aggregated data" stage. In logs it looks like this:

```
10:55:20.988391 [ 53 ] {} <Trace> HTTPHandler: Request URI: /?query_id=ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006&database=some_db
10:55:20.993291 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Debug> executeQuery: (from --, user: --)  --- QUERY ---
10:55:21.000491 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Debug> some_db.od (SelectExecutor): Key condition: (column 0 in 552-element set)
10:55:21.001854 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Debug> some_db.od (SelectExecutor): MinMax index condition: (column 0 in 552-element set)
10:55:21.018972 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Debug> some_db.od (SelectExecutor): Selected 3 parts by date, 3 parts by key, 7195 marks to read from 7 ranges
10:55:21.019191 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> some_db.od (SelectExecutor): Reading approx. 58941440 rows with 4 streams
10:55:21.019396 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> InterpreterSelectQuery: FetchColumns -> Complete
10:55:21.020418 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Debug> executeQuery: Query pipeline:
 Expression
  Expression
   ParallelAggregating
    Expression × 4
     Filter
      MergeTreeThread
10:55:21.020861 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> ParallelAggregatingBlockInputStream: Aggregating
10:55:21.027488 [ 62 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> Aggregator: Aggregation method: keys128   
10:55:21.029127 [ 64 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> Aggregator: Aggregation method: keys128   
10:55:21.038888 [ 56 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> Aggregator: Aggregation method: keys128   
10:55:21.046746 [ 48 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> Aggregator: Aggregation method: keys128   
10:55:21.116165 [ 48 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> Aggregator: Converting aggregation data to two-level.
10:55:21.119995 [ 56 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> Aggregator: Converting aggregation data to two-level.
10:55:21.124843 [ 64 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> Aggregator: Converting aggregation data to two-level.
10:55:21.180181 [ 62 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> Aggregator: Converting aggregation data to two-level.
10:55:26.468352 [ 48 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Debug> MemoryTracker: Current memory usage: 1.01 GiB.
10:55:27.356930 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> ParallelAggregatingBlockInputStream: Aggregated. 14485433 to 2196249 rows (from 221.030 MiB) in 6.336 sec. (2286233.713 rows/sec., 34.885 MiB/sec.)
10:55:27.356989 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> ParallelAggregatingBlockInputStream: Aggregated. 14929109 to 2225915 rows (from 227.800 MiB) in 6.336 sec. (2356259.030 rows/sec., 35.954 MiB/sec.)
10:55:27.357031 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> ParallelAggregatingBlockInputStream: Aggregated. 14148579 to 2173827 rows (from 215.890 MiB) in 6.336 sec. (2233068.097 rows/sec., 34.074 MiB/sec.)
10:55:27.357061 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> ParallelAggregatingBlockInputStream: Aggregated. 15344221 to 2260723 rows (from 234.134 MiB) in 6.336 sec. (2421776.094 rows/sec., 36.953 MiB/sec.)
10:55:27.357133 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> ParallelAggregatingBlockInputStream: Total aggregated. 58907342 rows (from 898.855 MiB) in 6.336 sec. (9297336.934 rows/sec., 141.866 MiB/sec.)
10:55:27.357158 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> Aggregator: Merging aggregated data       
10:55:56.117053 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Information> executeQuery: Read 58933982 rows, 1.10 GiB in 35.120 sec., 1678071 rows/sec., 32.01 MiB/sec.
10:55:56.117925 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Trace> virtual DB::MergingAndConvertingBlockInputStream::~MergingAndConvertingBlockInputStream(): Waiting for threads to finish
10:55:56.170074 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Debug> MemoryTracker: Peak memory usage (total): 1.64 GiB.
10:55:56.265958 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Debug> MemoryTracker: Peak memory usage (for query): 1.64 GiB.
10:55:56.266001 [ 53 ] {ef578bae-0aa1-11ea-8948-0242ac170006} <Information> HTTPHandler: Done processing query
```

So `Merging aggregated data` takes 29 sec out of total 35 sec (83%). But I can't find any information what this line even means. What does Clickhouse do while 'merging aggregated data'?

I checked the server performance, but it hadn't run out of memory or CPU time. CPU also wasn't working in `iowait` mode. So I just can't understand what limits Clickhouse performance. Does anyone know how I can fix slow `merging aggregated data`?

**EDIT**
Here is query:

```sql
SELECT site_id_from as on, site_id_to as off, sum(cnt)/23 as cnt
FROM some_db.od
WHERE timestamp_start in ('2019-10-01 00:00:00', '2019-10-01 01:00:00', ... , '2019-10-31 23:00:00') -- 552 keys
GROUP BY site_id_from, site_id_to
```

Here is table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_db.od (
    `timestamp_start` DateTime('Europe/Moscow'),
    `site_id_from` Int32,
    `site_id_to` Int32,
    `cnt` Float64
)
ENGINE = MergeTree() 
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(timestamp_start) 
ORDER BY timestamp_start;
```

Comment: `Merging aggregated data` it's the second step in two-level aggregation. 4 streams aggregated 1/4 piece each on the step and on the second step Aggregator combines results. It seems that your query has GROUPBY with_very_long_string. Is it?

Comment: I edited the question and added the query and the table definition. Actually both of them are extremely simple. I didn't make the point, that the problem is not permanent. I've tried the same query just now and it was completed in 5.5 sec. But when many (up to 10) people start executing queries like this, 'merging' get slow again and I can't understand where is a bottleneck.

Comment: >`5.5 sec. But when many (up to 10)`

it's expected. CH utilizes all CPU for 1 query. So 10 parallel queries work 10 times slower. This is a misuage of CH to run 10 parallel queries. Try pre-aggreagate numbers using MV https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8015#issuecomment-562383913

Answer (score 0):

try change table definition to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_db.od (
    `timestamp_start` DateTime('Europe/Moscow'),
    `site_id_from` Int32,
    `site_id_to` Int32,
    `cnt` Float64,
    INDEX ts (timestamp_start) TYPE minmax GRANULARITY 1

)
ENGINE = MergeTree() 
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(timestamp_start) 
ORDER BY site_id_from, site_id_to;
```

change sorting key can reduce time for GROUP BY
skip index can reduce time for WHERE IN search
https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/mergetree/#table_engine-mergetree-data_skipping-indexes